# AWS SAM Redeploys All TypeScript Functions Even No Code Change

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

Background:

Using AWS SAM typescript template (file type: Zip; Build with esbuild). And I have successfully deployed the clouformation stack.

The issue is: every time execute `sam build && sam deploy --config-env dev`, SAM will deploy function and RestAPI, even though I have not changed any code.

I also include some build CLI logs:

```
unning NodejsNpmBuilder:LockfileCleanUp
Manifest is not changed for (HelloWorldPublicFunction), running incremental build
Building codeuri: C:\xsrc\test\helper-funcs\lw-puller-v3\lw-functions runtime: nodejs18.x metadata: {'BuildMethod': 'esbuild', 'BuildProperties': {'Minify': True, 'Target': 'es2020', 'Sourcemap': True, 'EntryPoints': ['public.ts']}} architecture: x86_64 functions: HelloWorldPublicFunction
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:CopySource
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:CopySource
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:LinkSource
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:LinkSource
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:CopySource
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:LinkSource
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle
```

Any way it can ignore the function that has not changed? (I am going to include more functions, and do not want to re-deploy all functions if I only change one function code)

Answer (score 1):

For development, you can use `sam sync` to deploy only the code of the lambda you change.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/accelerating-serverless-development-with-aws-sam-accelerate/

For production, you must continue to use `sam build` + `sam deploy` to create an new and immutable artifact for your environment application.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is that when no code gets changed, but run `sam build && sam deploy` SAM keeps deploying to cloudformation. (which should not, as no code gets changed)

Comment: The log you shared is from the esbuild steps, which will run regardless of code change or not. It will build the lambda code and try to upload it to S3. If there is a checksum match, the S3 upload will be skipped, and CloudFormation Change Set execution will also be skipped in that stack. The behaviour is correct for `aws deploy`. The only way to skip it is using `aws sync`, but it is recommended to do it only for development environments and not production.

Comment: Thanks. I think the term 'checksum' you mentioned may be the key point. Do you know why without code change (TypeScript) the checksum still pass to deploy? Apparently without code change, it keeps deploying

Comment: It is the default behaviour of `sam deploy` with esbuild. The esbuild build process will happen to all lambda functions. The s3 upload will be skipped if they are the same checksum, but the esbuild will run regardless.

Comment: @Xin did you ever find resolution for this? running into the same issue and i think its also because typescript compilation is generating different checksum even when no changes.  i recall reading something on this a while ago, and i believe it had something to do with timestamps being part of the output, which would explain different checksum, but i dont recall how to fix

Comment: @matthewmturner still same. So have to just redeploy all.